# Assembly Language (Irvine)-a macro that waits for a keystroke and returns the key that was pressed

Tags: assembly, macros, ascii, masm, irvine16

A macro that waits for a keystroke and returns the key that was pressed. 
The macro should include parameters for the ASCII code and keyboard scan code.

I have the following code but I am getting two errors. The errors are below with my source code underneath them.

Errors:

> error A2006: undefined syV
>
> error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi
>   /Fo"Debug\ch10_01.obj" /Fl"zprob1.lst" /I "c:\Irvine" /W3
>   /errorReport:prompt  /Ta"....\ASM Solutions\ch10\ch10_01.asm"" exited
>   with code 1

Source Code:

```
 INCLUDE Irvine16.inc
ASSUME DS:_DATA

mReadkey MACRO ascii, scan
    mov ah,10h      ; BIOS keyboard input function
    int 16h
    mov scan,ah
    mov ascii,al
ENDM

.data
ascii BYTE ?
scan  BYTE ?
str1  BYTE "ASCII code: ",0
str2  BYTE "Scan code:  ",0

.code
main PROC
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

; Wait for a key; when the macro returns, the two arguments
; contain the ASCII code and scan code of the key.
mReadkey ascii, scan

; Display the values.
    mov edx,OFFSET str1
    call WriteString
    movzx eax,ascii
    call WriteHex
    call Crlf

    mov edx,OFFSET str2
    call WriteString
    movzx eax,scan
    call WriteHex
    call Crlf

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Errors are on Line 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to compile a 16-bit real mode code to a 32-bit protected mode executable. That won't work. Add a `/omf` to the command line of `ml.exe` and ensure that `link16.exe` will be used as linker.